# Differing Behavior With Pandas Boolean Operation

Tags: python, pandas

For the following test code, could someone explain why the contents of `test1` and `test2` differ for the third row (index 2)? I had code written a la `test1` and wasted a few hours trying to figure out why the code wasn't working before re-writing a la `test2` to solve it. Is it an order-of-operations thing within pandas for the one-liner used to generate `test1`?

```
import pandas as pd

# test data
dat1 = [1,1,2,1]
dat2 = ['a','b','c','d'] # only for building a multi-column DF, not otherwise used
dat3 = [False,False,True,False]

# build a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame( data={ "Data1":dat1, "Data2":dat2})

# first test
test1 = df['Data1']==1 | pd.Series(dat3)
print('==test 1==')
print(test1)

# second test
tmp1 = df['Data1']==1
tmp2 = pd.Series(dat3)
test2 = tmp1 | tmp2
print('==test 2==')
print(test2)
```

The output is

```
==test 1==
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
dtype: bool
==test 2==
0    True
1    True
2    True
3    True
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is caused due to operator precedence,try:

```
test1 = (df['Data1']==1) | pd.Series(dat3) # Note the parenthesis (df['Data1']==1)
```

Then you would see both are equal.

```
# first test
test1 = (df['Data1']==1) | pd.Series(dat3)
print('==test 1==')
print(test1)

# second test
tmp1 = df['Data1']==1
tmp2 = pd.Series(dat3)
test2 = tmp1 | tmp2
print('==test 2==')
print(test2)

==test 1==
0    True
1    True
2    True
3    True
dtype: bool
==test 2==
0    True
1    True
2    True
3    True
dtype: bool
```

---

When you do:

```
df['Data1']==1 | pd.Series(dat3)
```

This is evaluated as:

```
df['Data1'] == (1 | pd.Series(dat3))
```

To avoid this use parenthesis for each condition:

```
test1 = (df['Data1']==1) | pd.Series(dat3)
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications and explanation on how things are evaluated, I figured it must be something simple that like.